# CSS and JS files loading

Tags: asp.net, iis

Our web application is deployed over 2 WFE servers controlled by an NLB

Both servers have the same DLLS installed in the GAC also same web files, when opening the website at server A it works fine but in case of server B no styles and JS files are loaded.

Could it be an issue caused by IIS?

Comment: Does Firebug or IE's developer tools give you any clues?

Comment: Did you check the HTML rendered? are the references to css and js files accurate on server B?

Comment: yes same HTML is rendered on both servers

Comment: How do you check if you are hitting server A vs. server B when you are checking your website? Just want to clarify since you said servers are in NLB

Comment: I am accessing the application from within the server "localhost" while doing the test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the issue seemed to be with the web site created under IIS, I have removed and created it . it works fine now .

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions given to the APP POOl user

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the files to server, it may not reference to the correct path.
So it will be probobly work if you change the links of your `.css` and `.js` files.

```
eg. <script src="Scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
to <script src="http://www.yoursite.com/Scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```